# Problem Admin Panel

Tags: admin

I have a problem with the admin zone of my website, I put my ID and password, and I recevie this messagge, without beeing able to access the admin panel. Can anyone help me?  "Us[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your username/password is correct, remove cookies from your browser and try again.

Answer (score 0):

If deleting your browser's cache or trying to access from another browser didn't fixed , you can delete the files in

```
/var/session/
```

Comment: Deleting `var/session` is never an appropiate solution. http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/94589/keeping-customers-logged-in-after-deleting-var-session